# Liquidity Pool Addresses

Tags: uniswap, aave

I am looking to run some analytics on different liquidity pools in Curve, Uniswap and AAVE and for that I need their addresses. Is there any way I can get the list of pools and their contract addresses?

Answer (score 0):

You should consult with their documentations for the latest updates on deployment addresses should there be any change.

For example, you can find deployment addresses in [Uniswap documentation](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments).